# Is MapDB ready for production?

Tags: java, mapdb

Is MapDB ready for production? Are people using it in prod? What are your experiences?

http://www.mapdb.org/

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the first release was 17 days ago and the latest release is 0.9.1 I would assume it is not in production and the main person with any experience with it is the developer.